# How to notify Mac clients the need to change password?

Tags: windows-server-2003, mac-osx

It gets kind of annoying once a month to find out that our win server has locked my account.  
Whats the easiest way to push notifications to MacOSX clients that they should change password?

I need to direct the IT-guy on the right direction....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to bind your mac to the windows domain. You will then recieve a password notification when you log in. Change the password on your mac and it will update your keychain and your doamin account at the same time.

Comment: Thanks, I had no idea that it was possible. Seems buggy though after a quick Google-search but hopefully it will work...

Answer (score 0):

If joining the domain proves too cumbersome (my mac users at the old company could never tolerate it), Exchange 07 OWA (I couldn't blame them for hating Entourage) *finally* has password reminders built in.

Comment: Hm, I've installed 10.6 mostly to run Exchange with native MacOS apps.  Gotta find out if that would give some possibilites...

Comment: Suddenly there's something itching in my brain that you may need the "enhanced" OWA client to do that, which I'm betting won't run on Macs.  Yeah, sorry, I think I was wrong, unless your macs are in the habit of having an XP virtual running or something.